# Fluent email error Unable to compile template

Tags: c#, email, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5

I was updating my mvc 3.0 project to .net 4.0 and mvc 4.0 and find out that Fluent email stop working.
I was trying to use latest version http://www.nuget.org/packages/fluent-email/1.2.2 and pre release version as well http://www.nuget.org/packages/fluent-email/1.3.0-RazorEngine

But getting errors `Unable to compile template`

```
An exception of type 'RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateCompilationException' occurred in RazorEngine.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to compile template. Source file 'C:\Windows\TEMP\xrhyjmc5.0.cs' could not be found
```

May be some one know how to fix that?

My calling code:

```
                    email = Email
                    .From(model.FromEmail, model.Username)
                    .To(betsTipsterEmail)
                    .Subject(emailSubject)
                    .UsingTemplateFromFile(emailBodyFile, model)
                    .Body(model.Body)
                    .UsingClient(client);
```

My `Confirmation.html` template:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>
            Hi @Model.Username,

            bla<br /><br />
            bla<br /><br />
            <a href="@Model.Url">@Model.Url</a><br /><br />
            bla
        </p>
        <p>
            Kind Regards,<br /><br />
            bla
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

RazorEngine version 3.2.0
Was looking to this article http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2011/07/razorengine-templatecompilationexceptio.html but didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I've come across similar problems. Try wrapping each of your `@Model` calls with braces. eg. `@(Model.Username)`. The latest stable version for 1.3.0 was just released, you should update as well.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have this issue in .Net Core.
I'm using EmbeddedResources as my emails templates and I was adding razor render using DI like this: `services.AddRazorRenderer()`
After checking the unit tests of FluentEMail Razor and RazorLight doc
I figured out that I should pass `typeof(rootType)` to `services.AddRazorRenderer(typeof(rootType))` in order that my code works properly, without doing this RazorLight can't find the TemplateKey.

The exemple bellow taken from FluentEmail Razor tests shows how to add RazorRender:

```cs
public void Should_be_able_to_use_project_layout_with_viewbag()
        {
            var projectRoot = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            Email.DefaultRenderer = new RazorRenderer(projectRoot);

            string template = @"
@{
    Layout = ""./Shared/_Layout.cshtml"";
}
sup @Model.Name here is a list @foreach(var i in Model.Numbers) { @i }";

            dynamic viewBag = new ExpandoObject();
            viewBag.Title = "Hello!";
            var email = new Email(fromEmail)
                .To(toEmail)
                .Subject(subject)
                .UsingTemplate(template, new ViewModelWithViewBag{ Name = "LUKE", Numbers = new[] { "1", "2", "3" }, ViewBag = viewBag});

            Assert.AreEqual($"<h1>Hello!</h1>{Environment.NewLine}<div>{Environment.NewLine}sup LUKE here is a list 123</div>", email.Data.Body);
        }
```

FluentEmail offers 3 ways of adding RazorRenderer you can check [FluentEmailRazorBuilderExtensions.cs](https://github.com/lukencode/FluentEmail/blob/6ea1907a34899b0dc0334c5ff88ec3ab221da89f/src/Renderers/FluentEmail.Razor/FluentEmailRazorBuilderExtensions.cs), choose the right one.

If you're having the same issue please refere to [FluentEmail Razor Test](https://github.com/lukencode/FluentEmail/blob/master/test/FluentEmail.Razor.Tests/RazorTests.cs) and [RazorLight Doc](https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight#embeddedresource-source) and [FluentEmail issue](https://github.com/lukencode/FluentEmail/issues/153).